# Counting Values That Are Between an X and Y Coordinate

Tags: python, tuples, counter, counting

I have a whole set of data. This data is in x and y coordinates. I'm trying to write a program that counts the amount of data between x and y coordinates...
So for example, let's say I have

```
(3,4)
(6,3)
(7,6)
(5,5)
(6,7)
```

and I can only count the data where `5<x<7 and 4<y<6`

Then, the coords this program would count is:

```
(5,5)
(7,6)
```

So I would get 2.

I can figure out how to do this if I only set one constraint... For example if I just had a list of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and needed to count the numbers where `3<x<7`... I could do that. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle this if there's two constraints.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please review [ask] and show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `and` to state that both conditions should be satisfied. For example:

```
sum(5<=x<=7 and 4<=y<=6 for x,y in coord_list)
```

with `coord_list` the list of coordinates. Note that in order to satisfy the fact that the count should be 2, you should use *less than or equal* (`<=`) operators instead of *less than* operators (`<`).

This produces:

```
>>> coord_list = [(3,4),(6,3),(7,6),(5,5),(6,7)]
>>> sum(5<=x<=7 and 4<=y<=6 for x,y in coord_list)
2
```

You can obtain the *list* of coordinates, for instance using list comprehension:

```
[(x,y) for x,y in coord_list if 5<=x<=7 and 4<=y<=6]
```

If the number of elements in a point is arbitrary, it is better to use indexing:

```
[t for t in coord_list if 5<=t[0]<=7 and 4<=t[1]<=6]
```